# How to disable scroll back in SwiftUI TabView style page

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created a SwiftUI view that contains a `TabView` with a style page and needs to disable the ability to go back to the previous page once.

The final result should be like TikTok or Instagram reels but without the possibility of returning to see what I had seen before.

I tried with `DragGesture()` but it doesn't work on TabView.

Maybe I should do it with a scroll and if possible pull down to refresh, but I have no idea how to do this type of pagination.

My actual code is:

```
struct PagesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            TabView{
                ForEach(0..<10) { el in
                    ZStack{
                        Color(.purple)
                        VStack{
                            Text("Page \(el)")
                        }
                    }
                }.rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
            }.rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
                .frame(width: proxy.size.height)
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like maybe `TabView` isn't the best fit -- maybe just use a custom component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with tabView actually a lot of SwiftUI components still growing and you can't do with them what you used to do with some view in UIKit but here is a solution for what you want to do

```
var translation: CGFloat = 0
var currentPage = 0
var pageHeight: CGFloat = 0
var stackTopY: CGFloat = 0
var isDragging = false

struct ContentView: View {

@State var colors: [Color] = [.pink, .red, .green]
@State var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)


var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 5) {
        ForEach(0..<3) { index in
            GeometryReader { innerProxy in
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(colors[index])
                    .frame(width: innerProxy.frame(in: .global).size.width, height:innerProxy.frame(in: .global).size.height)
                    .coordinateSpace(name: "list_\(index)")
                    .task {
                        if index == colors.count-1 {
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                                let height = innerProxy.frame(in: .local).height
                                let remaining = abs(height - innerProxy.frame(in: .global).minY)
                                let total = height * CGFloat(index-1) + remaining
                                pageHeight = height
                                stackTopY = total
                                let stackX = innerProxy.frame(in: .local).width - innerProxy.frame(in: .global).maxX
                                location = CGPoint(x: stackX, y: total)
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, minHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        }
        
    }
    .position(location)
    .gesture(DragGesture()
        .onChanged({ value in
            guard  currentPage < colors.count - 1 else {return }
            if translation < value.translation.height  { return }
            
            isDragging = true
            translation = value.translation.height - translation
            location = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y + translation)
            translation = value.translation.height
        })
            .onEnded({ _ in
                guard isDragging else {return}
                guard  currentPage < colors.count - 1 else {return }
                
                isDragging = false
                currentPage += 1
                translation = 0
                let newY = stackTopY - (CGFloat(currentPage) * pageHeight)
                withAnimation {
                    location = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: newY)
                }
                
            }))
   }




}
```

create a new app then replace the contentView with this code and test it out. but i highly recommend that you use a UIKit collectionView  with swiftUI code to implement this pagination feature and use UIScrollview delegate to enable and disable scrolling in a specific direction

**UKit solution**

you can do something like this it's not perfect but you get the idea

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
   let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
//        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true  // enable this and remove pan gesture to scroll on both direction
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false // enable this and remove pan gesture to scroll on both direction
        return collectionView
    }()

var cells: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue]
var currentIndex: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scrollColelctionView(_:))))
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
        collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    ])
}


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cells.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
    
    cell.backgroundColor = cells[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

@objc func scrollColelctionView(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if gesture.velocity(in: gesture.view).y > 0 {
        return
    }
    
    switch(gesture.state) {
    case .began, .changed:
        
        let y = view.frame.height * CGFloat(currentIndex+1) + (gesture.translation(in: gesture.view).y * -1)
        collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: y,
                                                  width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height*0.5), animated: true)
    case .ended:
        currentIndex += 1
        if currentIndex >= cells.count {break}
        collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height * CGFloat(currentIndex),
                                                  width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), animated: true)
    default:
        break
    }
    gesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: gesture.view)
}




}
```

Comment: I tried with that but there is some issues on first app load and when switch between tabs of tabview... How can I done that I UIKit?

Comment: I updated my answer to add  UIkit solution. You can tweak it and customize it as you see fit it's just an idea. @alee